# repetitve timer doesnt work when looper is inside the runnable

Tags: java, android

I am testing a few things with TimerTask and Timers and android , and i noticed that if i put Looper inside the run () method, the TimerTask runs just once, even though i defined it to be repetitive.Any ideas why is that ?

here is the MainActivity part

```
  Timer timi=new Timer();
  timi.scheduleAtFixedRate(new locac(nok,this),10, 1000);
```

and here is the worker timerTask class

```
public void run ()


{






    Looper.prepare();


     int loto=23;
                 int lato=23;

     long time=1220227200;

          String test=String.valueOf(lato);
          String test3=String.valueOf(loto);
    String test1=String.valueOf(time);


    dbadapter mkola=new dbadapter(Ctx);
    mkola.openToWrite();

       mkola.insert(test,test1,test3);

 Looper.loop();





 }
```

as soon as i remove the Looper , it works nice.
i need the Looper because at a point i want to invoke some methods inside which initiate a Handler

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `TimrTask` never returns (because of the call to `Looper.loop()` )

Form The `Timertask` documentation, emphasis mine (Oracle Documentation, Android's is not that clear) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
 :

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a **single background thread** that
>   is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, **sequentially**. Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to
>   complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in
>   turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up"
>   and execute in rapid succession when (**and if**) the offending task
>   finally completes.

So what happens is that your TimerTask is run in the single thread of your Timer and as it's `run` method never returns it bloks the thread, which cannot run the new scheduled itereation of your `TimerTask` anymore.